# How to debug raspberry pi 4 connected fan

Tags: noobs, raspi-config

I'm completely new to this stack exchange, I've recently purchased a new case for my pi and a fan.
It's a 5V fan which i connect the red wire to `pin 4` and the ground to `pin 6`. While in power my fan won't start. I'm wondering if there is any default pi configuration that doesn't allow the fan to start under a certain temperature.

`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`

returns a temperature at `45 C` when booted, an soon reaches `65 C` but the fan still won't start.

How can i debug and figure out whether this is a fan (hardware) issue or software limitation? Do i have to run a python script for it?

Comment: Beware there's a difference between *pin 4* counting across and down, and *GPIO 4*.  The latter is not a 5V power pin and is the first pin in the 4th row (ie., it would be "pin 7").  If that's what you are connected to, that's the problem.  The same is true for pin 6, which is a ground pin -- but *GPIO 6* would be "pin 31".  Power (5 and 3.3V) and ground pins are actually not GPIOs, though they are on the breakout casually referred to as "the gpio pins" (although, again, they aren't really all gpios).

Comment: That's correct i will fix the question, yes they are connected on pin 4 and pin 6 , 5V and ground, it's supposed to start when the raspberry gets power is that correct?

Comment: pins 4 & 6 should put 5V on your fan [REF](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/). Check your polarity, make sure you're counting pins correctly, and make sure you've got a proper fan - one that will actually run from +5 VDC.

Comment: FYI, you should "bookmark" t[his handy reference to pin numbers](https://pinout.xyz/#).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to debug is your hardware. Use [this reference](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/) to verify that you have selected the correct pin numbers. If you have a voltmeter - or some simple circuit that will serve the same purpose - you should verify that there is 5V between the two pins you've chosen.

Wrt your questions about *"configuration that doesn't allow the fan to start under a certain temperature"*, *"software configurations"*, and *"Python scripts"*: The answer is **"No"**; none of those things affect the presence of 5V and GND on pins 4 and 6. Therefore, they are not the cause for you fan not running.

If your RPi boots and runs, and you have it connected to the correct pins, the best guess would be that your fan is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Pin 4 is connected to the 5 V power rail.

Pin 6 is connected to ground.

Pin 4 is always powered when the Pi is powered.

There is a fault with the Pi or the fan or the wiring between them.

Comment: I would like to hope there is a fan fault :(